# How can I multiply rows with a number using C#?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#

I have a dbf with a  field named "ppa" .the type of ppa is double. users enter  number (for example 0.023) in a textbox and select the dbf in a combobox . then click Run and program multiply 0.023 with each number of ppa and save the result in another field . what objects do i need for programming  ? How can i do this ?

Comment: Is this a GIS question at all...or a pure programming? You can read and edit a "DBF" in .Net/Java and other languages...why ask this question in a GIS forum?

Comment: ppa is calculated from Geoprocessing in ArcGIS .I have to do it in ArcGIS

Comment: But... What do you want? You want a script in python or maybe a add-in .. there are a lot of possibilities..

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a Python [script tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_creating_script_tools/001500000006000000/) or a [ModelBuilder](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_creating_tools_with_ModelBuilder/00150000001t000000/) model for this? Take advantage of the existing geoprocessing framework and save yourself a lot of code.

All you would do is [set up your parameters](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Setting_script_tool_parameters/00150000000n000000/) (input table, input float value) and set up [Calculate Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/) in the script/model to use the entered parameters, then double-click the tool/model from ArcToolbox to bring up the user interface, enter the values and click OK. About as simple as it gets really.

Also, if you run the tool/model from an MXD containing tables, it will automatically populate the input table parameter dropdown box with a list of available tables in the document.

Comment: thanks @blah238  . i'm creating certainty factor model tool  using c# and arcobject . it's a part of certainty factor model .

Comment: That doesn't mean much to me, so I guess the point still stands. Did you know that you can [call geoprocessing tools, including custom script tools and models from ArcObjects](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003rr000000)?

Comment: See also: [Using geoprocessing to develop applications](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001wt000000)